# Taxation on income sending from Hong Kong to India savings account

Tags: taxes, india, non-resident

I have been working in Malaysia for the last 1.5 years, my company has transferred my salary from Hong Kong to my Indian savings account for the last 18 months.

- Do I need to pay tax on this? All my funds have been transferred to an SBI savings account.
- I don't have an NRI account. Can anyone give me clear answer. To prove NRI, is it enough that stay out of India for more than 182 days or are any more details required?

Comment: Corrected the country tag (unless you for some reason forgot to explain why your question is regarding united states?)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to pay tax on this? All my funds transferred to SBI savings account.

Taxation depends on your Tax status in India. In a given financial year, if you are outside of India for more than 182 days, you are NRI for tax purposes. Any income you earn outside of India is not taxable. It is not relevant whether you transfer the funds to India or whether salary is credited in India or outside of India. Note any interest / rent or any other income that you earn in India is taxable in India.

> I dont have any NRI account. Can anyone give me clear answer. To prove NRI , is it enough that stay out of India more than 182 days or any more details required.

As per FMEA regulation, if you are an NRI, you should convert your savings accounts to an NRO account. You should open an NRE account. Not doing so is violation of the regulations. No penalties have been specified. However for keeping records for tax purposes it is advised to open an NRE account and have funds received in that account.

Answer (score 0):

India is not one of the two countries that taxes non-residents (United States and Eritrea), so you do not owe any taxes to Indian authorities. However, you will almost certainly owe income-taxes for your wages in Malaysia, as that is where you were working - and you certainly stayed their for more than the 183 days that is typically used to determine tax residence.